# Unit test for javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing

Sorry i'm pretty new to backend development and creating/making my unit test pass is blocker for me.

```
 ● VController › #findAll › ACL - should allow curator users to get all searched venues

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

      158 |     it('ACL - should allow admin users to get all venues', async () => {
      159 |       const response = await module.server
    > 160 |         .get('/api/venues')
          |                                   ^
      161 |         .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + adminAccessToken)
      162 |         .expect(200);
      163 |       const result = response.body;
```

I have this code for the unit test any idea why its failing even i have the said code below?

```
  it('ACL - should allow curator users to get all searched venues', async () => {
      const response = await module.server
        .get('/api/venues')
        .query({
          search: 'Festival'
        })
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + curatorAccessToken)
        .expect(200);
      const result = response.body;
      expect(result.length).toEqual(1);
      expect(result[0].name).toEqual('Festival');
    });
```

Comment: "*Expected: 1 Received: 0*" so `expect(result.length).toEqual(1);` fails because `result.length` is `0`. Are we supposed to be able to guess why that is?

Comment: @VLAZ i tried adding data in my database with some name 'Festival' on it. Can you maybe explain why i'm getting 0 result?

Comment: Does the order of `get`, `query`, `set`, `expect` matter? Seems weird to me to do `get` before setting `Authorization` header and setting `query`

Comment: Because `result.length` is zero. I'm sorry but I cannot *guess* what your code is doing. How am I supposed to tell *you* how *your* code behaves when all I have is a failing unit test in front of me?